# Laravel - How to update the employee table based on condition

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project I have these two models:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
          'id',
          'first_name',
          'last_name',
     'dept_code',
      'department_id',
          'is_updated',
      ];
 }

class Department extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'departments';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
          'id',
          'department_code',
      ];
 }
```

What i want to do is:

1. I want to select all the employees where is_updated = 0
2. Pick the dept_code from 1 above and compare it with department_code in departments table. Then pick the corresponding id of the departments table
3. update the department_id in each employees table with the value value of id in 2 above. and also set is_updated = 1

   ```
   public function handle()
   {
    $employeeid = Employee::where('is_updated', 0)->where('company_id', 1)->pluck('id');
    $employees = Employee::whereIn('id', $employeeid)->get();
    $employedept = Employee::where('company_id', 1)->get();

    foreach ($employees as $employee) {

       $departments = Department::select('id')->where('dept_code', $employee->dept_id)->where('company_id', 1)->first();

        $employedept->update([
            'department_id' => $departments->id
            'is_updated'   => 1,
               ]);
   }
   ```

How do I complete the code above to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function handle()
{
    $dept_codes = Employee::where('is_updated', 0)->where('company_id', 1)->pluck('dept_code')->toArray();
    $departments = Department::whereIn('department_code', $dept_codes)->where('company_id', 1)->get();
    foreach ($departments as $d) {
        Employee::where('dept_code', $d->department_code)
            ->where('company_id', 1)
            ->update(['department_id' => $d->id, 'is_updated' => 1]);
    }    
}
```

I have optimised the queries a bit to avoid querying the database on every iteration and reduced the number of updates to employees table also.

Let me know if you have any questions.